# Place two multiline TextViews with wrap_content width on both sides of the parent view

Tags: android, layout, textview, android-constraintlayout

Help me please achieve following arrangement of two TextViews:

[image]

1. On the left is a simple TextView with title, and on the right is another TextView with a Drawable on the left side of it (it is important because of it I can’t use `match_parent`). Both TextViews should be `wrap_content` and pressed to their side.
2. If one of the TextViews is too long, it should rest against another TextView and wrap its own text.
3. If both TextViews are long, then they should take up the same space. None of them should be pushed outside the parent view.

Comment: Use Linear layout with weight to achieve this.

Comment: @ShailendraMadda Unfortunately, I can't use weights because then the right TextView will always take up 50% of the space, despite the length of its text

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you tried [Flexbox layout](https://github.com/google/flexbox-layout)? Looks like it covers your case.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be the most correct way to do this. I've never tried using FlexLayout before.

Answer (score 6):

You can use both `LinearLayout` or `ConstraintLayout`, and the main here is `android:maxWidth` this we need to give one view and the other view will get adjust based on that.

`ConstraintLayout` example

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/start"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/end"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:text="Loooooooooong Texxxxxxxt!!!!!!!!!!!!" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/end"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        android:text="May be this is short"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`LinearLayout` Example:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Loooooooooong Texxxxxxxt!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:maxWidth="250dp"
        android:text="May be this is short with maxwidth"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: It's a solid solution and I like it. If there is't any more flexible option I'll check it as right answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/left"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="left" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/right"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/left"
        android:gravity="right" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

note that `left` `TextView` may occupy whole available space if got very long text, so you may add some `maxWidth` param - if its not supported by `TextView` itself then you may wrap first one into `LinearLayout` (which supports `maxWidth` for shure). another way may be to use `TableLayout` and `TableRow` views or `ConstraintLayout`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I appreciate your effort.

Comment: consider upvoting/accepting answer if helpful :) good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Check this out

**`activity_main.xml`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/constraintLayout"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/startTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="On"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="32sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/endTextView"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/endTextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:text="If one of the TextViews is too long"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:drawableStartCompat="@android:drawable/ic_btn_speak_now"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/startTextView"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

**`MainActivity.java`**

```
 private TextView startTV, endTV;
    private ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
        startTV = findViewById(R.id.startTextView);
        endTV = findViewById(R.id.endTextView);


        constraintLayout.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int systemWidth = Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;

                int startTVWidth = startTV.getMeasuredWidth();
                int endTVWidth = endTV.getMeasuredWidth();

                if ((startTVWidth + endTVWidth) >= systemWidth) {

                    if (startTVWidth > endTVWidth) {

                        startTV.setMaxWidth(systemWidth - endTVWidth - 24);

                        startTV.setPadding(12, 12, 12, 12);
                        endTV.setPadding(12, 12, 12, 12);

                    } else if (endTVWidth > startTVWidth) {

                        endTV.setMaxWidth(systemWidth - startTVWidth - 24);

                        startTV.setPadding(12, 12, 12, 12);
                        endTV.setPadding(12, 12, 12, 12);
                    }
                }
            }
        }, 1);
    }
```

A bit long. But this works.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I really appreciate your efforts. But I think this solution is too complicated for such a task.

Comment: @Nikolay This is the only solution I can find to use `wrap_content` on both `TextView`s without clipping and also for the big `TextView` to rest against another `TextView`. I couldn't find any less-complicated solutions... Thank you. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 1):

Do try this -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/text2"
    android:text="TextView1" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/basket"
    android:text="TextView2" />
</RelativeLayout>
```