# Row with two Text in Constraint fashion in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, row, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I want to include two Text in a Row where the first Text's width is upto the start of 2nd Text, like this
[image]

I am trying Modifier weight but the result achieved is not the same.
Is there a way to do it by using Row itself and not ConstraintLayout.

EDIT :

```
Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
          Text(
            "Some long title abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yzzzzz Some long title abcd efgh ijkl mnop qrst uvwx yzzzzz",
            maxLines = 1,
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            modifier = Modifier.weight(5f)
          )
          Text("View all", modifier = Modifier.weight(1f))
        }
```

This works, please suggest a better solution if I am missing something.

EDIT 2 :
Its giving me results like this:
[image]
I want the Title to start from the beginning of Row

Comment: Add the code you have already tried. The `weight` modifier should work

Comment: Sorry, I was adding max width to the first text as well.. Thats why it wasn't working

Comment: Check if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64746671/9652621) question helps you

Comment: You can to remove weight from the second `Text`: in this case second size will be calculated at first, and then first text will take the remaining space. Check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68972289/3585796) for more details.

Comment: When using small text for Title, its not starting from the beginning of Row, rather occupies center position from the available space.

Comment: @PhilipDukhov I have updated the question with Screenshots. Please guide me.

Comment: @Ali_Waris Are you sure you've removed `weight` from the second text and left on the first one? If so add your updated code

Comment: When I applied a weight of 1f to the first Text and set its width to fillMaxWidth, it works as expected

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use something like:

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {
    Text(
        "Short title",
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        modifier = Modifier.weight(1f)
    )
    Text("View all")
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What if we are expecting both text views ("Short title" and "View all") to be next to one another, but expand to the max width of parent.

Comment: @Bheem Just add fill = false and it works. 
modifier = Modifier.weight(1f, fill = false)

Comment: @Bheem You can check this example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73582825/how-to-chain-two-text-with-constraintlayout/73584535#73584535

Answer (score 11):

Just for comparison, this is the same solution but done with  `ConstraintLayout`:

```
ConstraintLayout(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
) {
    val (title, viewAll) = createRefs()

    Text(text = "View all", Modifier
        .background(Color.Green)
        .constrainAs(viewAll) {
            top.linkTo(parent.top, 8.dp)
            end.linkTo(parent.end, 8.dp)
        })

    Text(text = "Short title",
        maxLines = 1,
        overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
        modifier = Modifier
            .background(Color.White)
            .constrainAs(title) {
                top.linkTo(parent.top, 8.dp)
                start.linkTo(parent.start, 8.dp)
                end.linkTo(viewAll.start, 8.dp)
                width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
            })
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, @Roberto Leinardi 
I up voted your nice answer

Answer (score 0):

if you have all single line text then simply use this

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    Text(text = "Start")
    Text(text = "End")
}
```

When we are using `horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween` we don't need to assign `weights` if texts are always going to be a single line.

Similarly for three `Texts`

```
Row(
    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
    horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
) {
    Text(text = "Start")
    Text(text = "Center")
    Text(text = "End")
}
```

and to further have them neatly `CenterVertically`

```
{
    Text(
         text = "Start",
         modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
   )
    Text(text = "End",
         modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.CenterVertically)
   )
}
```