# How to chain two text with ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-text

I'm using `ConstraintLayout` for `Compose` and I'm facing a problem here.

I have a `Text` that is :

```
Text(
   text = "Whatever",
   overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
   maxLines = 1,
   modifier = Modifier
     .padding(start = 16.dp)
     .constraintAs(title) {
        start.linkTo(parent.start)
        bottom.linkTo(parent.bottom, 24.dp)
        end.linkTo(images.start)
        width = Dimension.fillToConstraints
     },
   )
```

That's a simple `Text` and then I have a `Row` where it's a dynamic number of `Image` for instance :

```
Row(
  modifier = Modifier
      .constraintAs(images) {
          start.linkTo(title.end)
          top.linkTo(title.top)
          bottom.linkTo(title.bottom)
          end.linkTo(parent.end, 16.dp)
       },
) {
  repeat(dynamicNumber) {
    Image(
       painter = painterResource...
       modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 3.dp)
   )
  }
}
```

The problem I'm having here is with this code when the "Title" is long it fits perfect and is what I expect see the image below :

[image]

The problem is when the text is small the images are stick to the end because I've put `end.linkTo(parent.end)`

This is how it looks now :
[image]

This is how should be :
[image]

The idea is if the text is large, then its width is enough to don't overlap the images and when it's on its limit add the ellipse, then if the text is small the images should be not in the end but just stick to the small text.

What I'm missing?

Comment: remove `end.linkTo(parent.end, 16.dp)` inside the Row

Comment: @AnaniyaJemberu if he does so then if the text is too long it will excel the screen and the images won't show because there's no limit for the `Image`

Comment: never thought of that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of using a `ConstraintLayout`, you can use a simple `Row` applying a `weight(1f,false)` modifier to the `Text`.
Using `fill=false` the element will not occupy the whole width allocated.

```
   Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {

        Text(
            text = "Whatever",
            overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
            maxLines = 1,
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(start = 16.dp)
                .weight(1f, false)
        )

       repeat(dynamicNumber) {
            Image(
             painter = painterResource...
             modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = 3.dp)
            )
       }
   }
```

[image]

Comment: I've tried to implement this but the images are not center vertically, how I fix this? I was using constriants to center them, plus the Row now is in the top of the screen and not below my other views.