# Set decimal precision based on textview width

Tags: java, android

Since there are many different phone screen sizes, I'd like to know if there is a smile way to change the display precision of my numbers to change to fit the textview label.  Currently its just hardcoded to a fixed number.

```
    TextView field = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textpercent1);
    double y = 34.434359875385;
    field.setText(String.format("%.4f%%",y));
```

On a small phone, it might want "34.4344%", on a large phone, maybe "34.43435975%".  I'd rather not hard code in each possibility.

Comment: you might want to calculate the widths and manually do the rounding of numbers. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64889106/9652621) is a similar answer I wrote a while back, hope it helps. :)

Comment: that's pretty much what I was thinking, I had hoped android had something more convenient and simple

Comment: Not to my knowledge, sadly :(